# Is it an Android's potential support package for Material Design?

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design

Does the package named "design" that you can find in [Android support sources](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/7cc23e31790b02f31707b36655401a69b8e6ebc2/design) meant for supporting material design:

If yes, how to use it in Android Studio because this doesn't work

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-design:+'
```

Comment: There is no support library called design. You can find all support libraries here - https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

Comment: I know official way, but go the previous link or this one: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/7cc23e31790b02f31707b36655401a69b8e6ebc2

Answer (score 0):

The package name is wrong try with:

```
com.android.support:design:22.2.0
```